# Stop bash on error same as "set -e" in script file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have an external command to produce some bash commands, let's call it `gen_commands`, it produces a list of commands that I need to run with `bash`, but if any command fails I need to stop and exit. To stop it on error I'm writting the result of `gen_commands` to temporary script file appending `set -e` at the beggining:

```sh
echo "#!/bin/bash" > tmp.sh
echo "set -e" >> tmp.sh
gen_commands >> tmp.sh
chmod +x tmp.sh
./tmp.sh
rm tmp.sh
```

It would look much cleaner if I can run it with one line:

```sh
gen_commands | bash
```

but in that case `bash` ignores errors. Is it possible to configure bash to fail on error without writting to sccript file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a command group to combine the output of multiple commands into one stream:

```
{ echo "set -e"; gen_commands; } | bash
```

However, you can simply pass `-e` as an option to `bash` as well:

```
gen_commands | bash -e
```

From the man page:

> OPTIONS
>
> All of the single-character shell options documented in the description
>          of the **set** builtin command can be used as options  when  the  shell  is
>          invoked.